# YouTube Copyright

Tags: copyright, youtube

I am interested in making a trailer channel, but I need to know if I can just take recently released movie trailers and upload the videos to my channel.

It might sound like a dumb question, but I am just wondering if I can do this without penalty (i.e YouTube deleting my account)

For Ex. Taking the new star trek trailer and uploading it to my channel.

Great answers so far, however I want to have a channel based solely on Trailers. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Use an email you don't mind losing if you get banned from youtube with it. Otherwise to get started register an account with that email and start posting away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Youtube can close your channel for too many copyright infringements. Trailers are popular and are on other peoples channels. It's a matter of how many complaints they receive against your account. Also many people write disclaimers saying the videos, music etc belong to their respective copyright holders. That doesn't hold up, you are just admitting you know you're breaking the law. IMHO it's not the end of the world if you re-post an official trailer. You may get an email warning worst case they close your channel.